# Returning current version of each record using Google Cloud Datastore query

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

I am using a relay/graphql/googlecloud setup for a project that saves data immutably.

I have a set of fields that create a new record each time a modification is made to any of the fields structured like so:

```
Project
- Start Date
- End Date
- Description
- ...
- ...
```

The first time a project is created it is saved with a timestamp and a version number. For example:

```
1470065550-1
```

Any modifications after this creates a new version number but still uses the same timestamp.

```
1470065550-2
```

Bearing in mind that it is immutable there will potentially be a lot of versions of one project. If there are also a lot of projects this could result in a large number of records being fetched

If I want to fetch a list of projects from the datastore returning only the latest version of each one what would be the best way of going about this? As the version number increments i never know which one is the latest.

For example if I had rows containing 2 projects, both with multiple versions and I want to fetch the latest version of each:

```
1470065550-1
1470065550-2
1470065550-3
1470065550-4
1470065550-5
1470065550-6
1470065550-7 <--- Current Version for 1470065550
1567789887-1
1567789887-2
1567789887-3 <--- Current Version for 1567789887
```

Based on the rows above I need the query to just return the latest version of the two projects:

```
1470065550-7 <--- Current Version for 1470065550
1567789887-3 <--- Current Version for 1567789887
```

Comment: "As the version number increments i never know which one is the absolute latest." <-- this doesn't make sense. Can you please explain why you can't know the latest version number of a project?

Comment: I have added an example. Sorry I was not very clear initially

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change your tag to [google-cloud-datastore] instead of [google-cloud-storage] because you're probably missing people who are truly experts on datastore.

But just to offer my two cents on your question: It may be easiest to add a field for "current" and then use a transaction to switch it atomically.  Then it is an easy filter for use in any other query.

If you can't do that, it's a bit tricky to answer your question because you haven't given us the query you are building to get this set of results.  The typical way of getting a max value is to sort and set a limit of 1 like so:

```
var query = datastore
   .createQuery('Projects')
   .order('timestamp')
   .limit(1);
```

But given the way you are storing the data, I don't think you can do this when you run over from -9 to -10 because -10 usually comes before -9 in lexicographical sorts (I didn't check how this works in datastore, however).  You might need to zero pad.

Comment: I am currently using a GQL query. The problem is that it does not have a GROUP BY which you can use in a mySQL query to achieve the result I am looking for